# TabBar DidSelect not detect tabBar item & not called

Tags: ios

i have 4 items in tabBar and 1 center button

tabBar in the first item should be black and in other items should be white & the image of the center point should be changed too. I write in the did select item

```
if tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: item) == 0 {
do something !
}
```

this is called but when i press on items. I need func to be called even if i don't press or i changed the tab item through code with a button in a view. It doesn't call so the tab bar colour didn't change cause it's not called so what can i do please !

Comment: Punctuation is good.